# Regexp change url of string with rel=attachment

Tags: regex

I have an url like this

```
<a href="https://www.mysite.com/blog/?attachment_id=638" rel="attachment wp-att-638">
```

How can i create a regular expression to match the url only and replace that?
The regexp should only match where rel has the value attachment, like above.

Comment: Regex is not a good tool for parsing HTML (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  In any case, you need to say what language you are using.

Comment: you mean the value of href? or certain part of the url?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
/[<]a[^>]+(?:(?:href=["]([^"]+)["][^>]+rel)|(?:rel[^>]+href=["]([^"]+)["]))/
```

the submatch at index 1 or 2 will contain the url.

Comment: That will match all links, i need it to match the links that has the rel value "attachment"

Comment: @AntonGildebrand Then please edit your question and explain *exactly* what you're trying to achieve.